# Derivation of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, scattering

I was trying to understand the derivation of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation in Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, Section 6.1. Our teacher presented a much simpler derivation, similar to that on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation#Derivation). My question is:

What is the motivation for such a complicated derivation? Is it just to get around the inversion of the operator?

Comment: Not having a copy of Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics or your teacher's notes, it's hard to comment.

Comment: Quantum Mechanics (Leslie E. Ballentine),you'll find your answer there,great book.

Comment: [More on LSE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+lippmann).

Comment: The wikipedia material at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation#Derivation
does not (23rd Jan 2024), as I understand matters, actually contain a derivation of the equation!

Comment: For a proof, of what you might think of as the naive form of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation, see at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4850513/553318