# How is Lippmann-Schwinger equation derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, scattering, greens-functions

I'd like to know the derivation of [Lippmann-Schwinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation) (LSE) in operator formalism and on what assumptions it is based. I consulted [the Ballentine book](http://www-dft.ts.infn.it/~resta/fismat/ballentine.pdf) as advised [in this Phys.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161832/), but I still don't understand it.

It states that if LSE holds:
$$ |\psi\rangle = |\phi\rangle + G_0(E^+) V|\psi\rangle \tag{1}$$

then $H|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle$ or alternatively 
$$ V|\psi\rangle = (E-H_0)|\psi\rangle \tag{2}$$

Here $H_0 |\phi\rangle = E |\phi\rangle$ and $G_0(E^+)$ signifies a limit $G_0(E+i\eta)$ as $\eta \to 0$.

Now, it is easy to verify that $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$. But, as the book states, $(1)$ contains more information and I think that $(2) \nRightarrow (1)$. So how is LSE truly derived? If we consider problem $(2)$ then obviously $ |\psi\rangle = G_0(E^+) V|\psi\rangle $ is also a solution. Why do we need $|\phi\rangle$?

And lastly how is $|\psi\rangle$ defined? If it is defined by $(2)$ then why does it have the same eigenvalues as $|\phi\rangle$ has for $H_0$? Why is it even true that the spectral problem $(2)$ has a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time, an (*elastic*) scattering problem can be reduced in :

- An incoming initial wave / quantum state $|\phi\rangle$, which most of the time is taken to be a plane wave / free state $|\textbf{k}\rangle$ eigenstate of the free hamiltonian :
  $$
  \hat{\mathcal{H}}_0\,|\phi\rangle=E\,|\phi\rangle\quad\text{with}\quad\hat{\mathcal{H}}_0=-\frac{\Delta}{2}
  $$
- A scattering potential $\hat{V}(\hat{\textbf{x}})$, which a priori can be anything (spherically symmetric, disordered, etc).

Obviously, in that case $|\phi\rangle$ is no longer an eigenstate of the full hamiltonian :
$$
\hat{\mathcal{H}}=\hat{\mathcal{H}}_0+\hat{V}
$$

Of course what you want is to find such eigenstate that you noted $|\psi\rangle$, so that :
$$
\hat{\mathcal{H}}\,|\psi\rangle=E\,|\psi\rangle\quad\text{i.e.}\quad (E-\hat{\mathcal{H}}_0)|\psi\rangle=\hat{V}|\psi\rangle
$$
Such equation is nothing but a differential equation. To solve it, you have first to find the homogene solution, i.e. without the second member $\hat{V}|\psi\rangle$. It's easy to see that the homogene solution $|\psi\rangle_{h}$ is $|\phi\rangle$.

The particular solution $|\psi\rangle_p$ can be foud by playing a little bit with the formulas. By definition of the free (retarded) Green function
$$
\hat{G}_0(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon-\hat{\mathcal{H}}_0+\mathrm{i}\eta}
$$
you have :
$$
\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\hat{G}_0^{-1}(\epsilon)=E-\hat{\mathcal{H}}_0=\hat{G}_0^{-1}(E)\quad\text{with}\quad E=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\epsilon+\mathrm{i}\eta
$$
Then follows 
$$
\hat{G}_0^{-1}(E)|\psi\rangle=\hat{V}|\psi\rangle\quad\text{i.e.}\quad|\psi\rangle=\hat{G}_0(E)\hat{V}|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle_p
$$

As always, the general solution of a differential equation is the sum of the homogene and particular solutions :
$$
|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle_h+|\psi\rangle_p=|\phi\rangle+\hat{G}_0(E)\hat{V}|\psi\rangle
$$
which is the so called Lippmann Schwinger equation.

Comment: So why does $| \psi \rangle$ and $| \phi \rangle$ have the same eigenenergies $E$?

Comment: Because such derivation is only valid for **elastic** scattering, i.e. the energy $E$ is conserved through the all process.

Comment: @dolun: Excellent answer. But if you compare $(E-H_0)|\psi\rangle = V|\psi\rangle$ in position space with the form of a nonhomogeneous ODE, then they don't actually match.

Comment: I do not believe in this answer.

Comment: This answer, has begun to look, almost like nonsense!

Answer (score 2):

For a proof, of what might be thought of as, the naive form of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation, see at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4850513/553318

**Other Information**

Sakurai$^1$  Section 7.1, 'The Lippmann-Schwinger Equation', discusses this naive form of the equation, he say's that on it's own it has no meaning, but that this may be addressed by making $E$ slightly complex.

He then gives the Lippmann-Schwinger equation in the form

> \begin{equation*}
>       |\psi^{(\pm )} \rangle =|\phi \rangle+\frac{ 1 }{ E-H_0\pm i\epsilon    }V|\psi^{(\pm )}\rangle \tag{7.1.6} \end{equation*}

---

I would like to explain why I do not believe in dolun's answer, dated July 17, 2015.

The answer of dolum, dated July 17, 2015, uses the idea expressed in the word equation, given below, but I don’t think this idea should be used here.

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    {
    A ~solution ~to ~ an~ inhomogenous~ differential~ equation
    }
    \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
    {
    A~ solution~ to~the~ associated~ homogenous~differential ~equation
    }\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
    {
    A~ particular ~solution~ to~ the~ inhomogenous ~differential ~equation
    }\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

The idea makes sense when we have a linear operator, $L$ say, and the following situation,

\begin{align*}
    L\phi_h(x)&=0 \\
    L\psi_p(x)&=f(x)
\end{align*}
but we have, with $(E-H_0)=L$, $V=f(x)$,
\begin{align*}
    L\phi_h(x)&=0 \\
    L\psi_p(x)&=f(x)\psi_p(x)
\end{align*}

I am assuming one spatial dimension in the above.

---

**To be explicit.**

When we have the "inhomogenous" equation, (1), given below
\begin{equation*}
    (E-H_0)\psi  =V\psi  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
and we know for non-zero $\phi_h$ and $\psi_p$
\begin{align}
    (E-H_0)\phi_h &=0  \tag{2}\\
    (E-H_0)\psi_p  &=V\psi_p  \tag{3}
\end{align}
$[ \phi_h+\psi_p]$ does not satisfy ($\mathbf{1}$)!

You can see this by adding ($\mathbf{2}$) and ($\mathbf{3}$), note that $(E-H_0)$ is a linear operator, giving

\begin{equation*}
    (E-H_0)[ \phi_h+\psi_p] =V\psi_p
\end{equation*}
so ($\mathbf{1}$) is not satisfied.

What would be required for ($\mathbf{1}$) to be satisfied, is
\begin{equation*}
    (E-H_0)[ \phi_h+\psi_p ]  =V[ \phi_h+\psi_p ] 
\end{equation*}

**Reference:**

1, J.J.Sakurai, Ed San Fu Tuan, Modern Quantum Mechanics Revised Edition, Addison-Wesley Publishing Company (1994).

Comment: Thanks. Your point about dolun's answer makes sense. I recall reading Sakurai's explanation and didn't get the "need to make E slightly complex" part. Sounds like hand waving. Do you understand it?

Comment: @Minethlos I guess it will make, at least some expressions in the theory well defined, in terms of taking limits as $\epsilon~ \to 0$.

Comment: For a proof, of what you might think of as the naive form of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation, see at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4850513/553318