# Is Hamiltonian a differential operator in second quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, second-quantization

Normally, a free particle Hamiltonian is written

$$ \hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \Delta $$

which is a differential operator because Laplacian $\Delta$ is.

On the other hand, in second quantization notation a Hamiltonian for free particle system is

$$ \hat{H} = \sum_j \varepsilon_j a^\dagger_j a_j $$

where $j$ are states with energies $\varepsilon_j$ and creation operator $a^\dagger_j$. It is not obvious if this is a differential operator.

**Foundation**: For example, the result known as [Lippmann-Schwinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation) assumes in [its derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194085/how-is-lippmann-schwinger-equation-derived) that the Hamiltonian is a differential operator so Schrödinger equation can be solved as a differential equation. Is it true in second quantization notation, as well?

Comment: What do you mean by differential operator? In the usual mathematical sense of the term, the second quantization operators are not differential operators. They are linear operators acting on a suitable Hilbert space, but not partial or pseudo differential operators.

Comment: Note that the derivation in the linked answer does not need to make any assumptions about whether $H$ is a differential operator. Exactly the same manipulations could be performed for a finite-dimensional matrix: it is just matrix inversion, after all. In the case of an infinite-dimensional matrix the "inverse" is more frequently called the Green's function, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Formally, $\hat{H}$ is not a differential operator but a linear operator on the (Hilbert) space of states. Technically one should always write (using the one-particle case as an example):

$$ \langle x | \hat{H} | \psi \rangle \equiv -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \langle x | \psi \rangle \equiv -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi(x) $$

Where $|x\rangle$ is a position eigenstate, $|\psi \rangle$ is the state the particle is in, and $\psi(x)$ is the corresponding wavefunction. That is, $\hat{H}$ is only the Laplacian in the *position representation*. This is so even in standard QM.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I don't think so. The crucial thing there is expressing the solution as a sum of particular and homogenous solutions. If $H_0$ was simply a linear operator then "particular" solution would suffice.

Comment: @Minethlos The homogeneous solution is just a zero eigenvector of the linear operator $(E - H_0)$. It is clear that one can always add such a zero eigenvector to the solution of $(E - H_0)\lvert \psi\rangle = V\lvert\psi\rangle$. So I don't see any need to restrict the conclusions to a statement about differential/infinite-dimensional operators.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Yes, but how do you justify adding it? What determines the form of this general solution? Why not add, say, $2|\phi\rangle$? (Here $|\phi\rangle$ is the homogeneous solution.)

Comment: @Minethlos Exactly the same question arises in the differential equation case. Strictly speaking you should add some undefined multiple $\alpha \lvert \phi\rangle$. The solution is then determined up to an unknown constant $\alpha$. It is never OK to just choose the prefactor ad hoc. Generally, the solution of such an equation is undetermined up to an arbitrary vector from the kernel of $(E - H_0)$. In the case of a differential equation this vector is determined by boundary conditions. For a scattering problem, this should probably be that the state is asymptotically an incoming plane wave.

Comment: @MarkMitchison In ODEs homogeneous solution already contains undetermined constants, I assumed it was the case here. Why is it true that the *general* solution to operator equation must contain a vector from the kernel of the operator? Maybe you could reference a book where I could read about this?

Comment: @Minethlos Yes but you only determine the constants once you add both the homogeneous and particular solutions. So the relative weight of the homogeneous and particular solutions is determined by the boundary conditions or other constraints. The general solution is just that: the most general thing you can write down that solves the equation. Afraid I don't have any mathematical references. However one does frequently see Green's functions techniques used in finite-dimensional scattering problems, e.g. the Landauer-Buttiker transport formalism.

Comment: @MarkMitchison very happy to see someone point out that Green functions are analogous to matrix inversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression 
$$
\hat{H}=\sum_j \varepsilon_j\,a_j^\dagger a_j
$$
is not the most general expression for free particles hamiltonian because it implies that you already found the eigenvalues $\varepsilon_j$ and diagonalized $\hat{H}$, i.e. already solved the Schrödinger equation.

Maybe you should look at the problem in a different basis. Let say $\{\vert j\rangle\}_j$ is a single particle state basis. Then you can chose to express $\hat{H}$ in another one particle basis, the position state basis $\{\vert x\rangle\}_x$ for instance.

The associated change of basis on the $a$ and $a^\dagger$ operators is perfomed with :
$$
a(x)=\sum_j \langle x\vert j\rangle\,a_j\,.
$$
Conversly, one can change back to the previous basis with :
$$
a_j=\int\mathrm{d}x\,\langle x\vert j\rangle\,a(x)
$$
Then you get the general expression of $\hat{H}$ in such basis :
$$
\hat{H}=\int\mathrm{d}x\,a^\dagger(x)\left[\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}\right]a(x)
$$
Such expression gives you back the fact that $\hat{H}$ is kind of a sum on one particle differential operators , provided that :
$$
\hat{p}=-\mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_x
$$

Answer (score 1):

A 1-particle Hilbert space (neglecting spin for simplicity) is usually modelled as $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ which is a function space, and the Hamiltonian is a differential operator. N-particle Hilbert spaces are usually constructed as tensor products of this 1-particle Hilbert space, but there exists an isomorphism such that you can again interpret them as function spaces. E.g. for 2 particles you have

$L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes L^2(\mathbb R^3) \simeq L^2(\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3)$.

So you can again interpret the Hamiltonian as a differential operator on these spaces.

The Fock space on which your second-quantized operators act is modelled as a direct sum of all N-particle Hilbert spaces. But unfortunately I don't know a simple way how this Fock space could be modelled as a function space. So my guess is: No, the Hamiltonian in second quantization is not a differential operator.

Comment: Does [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space#Relation_to_Bargmann-Fock_space) give the required interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

The second-quantization hamiltonian you wrote above is the hamiltonian for a collection of independent harmonic oscillators, where the quantities oscillating are now the amplitudes of the normal modes of the field being quantized. So, yes, the hamiltonian is a differential operator on the space complex functions of $N$ variables, one for each normal mode. Explicitly:
$$
\hat{H}f(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_i,\ldots,\phi_N) = \sum_j^N \varepsilon_j a^{\dagger}_j a_j f(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_i,\ldots,\phi_N) = \sum_j^N \varepsilon_j(-\frac{d^2}{d\phi_j^2} + \phi_j^2 - \frac{1}{2}) f(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_i,\ldots,\phi_N)
$$
(in suitably chosen units) where $\phi_i$ is the amplitude of the $i^{th}$ normal mode.